# MEAN.js $http.get() return index html content instead of json file

Tags: meanjs

I'm doing a web app based on original MEAN.js framework. When I want to request local json test file using $http.get() method in my AngularJS file, it returned my index html content.Is it a routing problem? I didnot change the original mean.js routing code(https://github.com/meanjs/mean), just added a $http.get() method in home.client.controller.js file. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely happening, because you didn't define an endpoint for that particular GET request in your app.

Everytime you make a request to your server (for example a GET request to `/my-request`) nodejs/express are configured in MEAN.js so that your server will try to find the endpoint for that request, if it does not find any, that request will be handled by this particular code block (specified in `/modules/core/server/routes/core.server.routes.js`):

```
// Define application route
app.route('/*').get(core.renderIndex);
```

Which will basically render the index view.

I'm not sure if you're using a custom module or not, eitherway, if you want that request to be handled in a different way in MEAN.js, you can specify your endpoint in your custom module routes file (or in `core.server.controller.js`) like so:

```
// Define application route
app.route('/my-request').get(core.sendMyJSON);
```

Be careful, because this route must be placed **before** the one I mentioned earlier, otherwise your request will still be handled the same way and the index view will be rendered and served again.

Then you will have to create the controller that should be called to handle that request:

```
exports.sendMyJSON = function (req, res) {
    // logic to serve the JSON file
};
```

This way you should be able to get it done with a few adjustments.

**Side note:**
I'm not entirely sure but I think if you place your JSON file in the public directory of your app you should be able to directly access it without the need for the extra logic.